# CSS: How to have position:absolute div inside a position:relative div not be cropped by an overflow:hidden on a container

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have 3 levels of `div`:

- *(In green below)* A top level `div` with `overflow: hidden`. This is because I want some content (not shown here) inside that box to cropped if it exceeds the size of the box.
- *(In red below)* Inside this, I have `div` with `position: relative`. The only use for this is for the next level.
- *(In blue below)* Finally a `div` I take out of the flow with `position: absolute` but that I want positioned relative to the red `div` (not to the page).

I'd like to have the blue box be taken out of the flow and expand beyond the green box, but be positioned relative to the red box as in:

[image]

However, with the code below, I get:

[image]

And removing the `position: relative` on the red box, now the blue box is allowed to get out of the green box, but is not positioned anymore relative to the red box:

[image]

Is there a way to:

- Keep the `overflow: hidden` on the green box.
- Have the blue box expand beyond the green box and be positioned relative to red box?

The full source:

```css
#d1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #efe;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 125px;
}

#d2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #fee;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#d3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  background: #eef;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="d1" >
  <div id="d2" >
    <div id="d3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clarification: So you want the blue box (the inner-most div) to be able to overflow out of the green box (the outer-most div) but keep overflow hidden on the green box? So basically, have overflow hidden on everything in the green box EXCEPT the blue box, is that right?

Comment: Anthony, yes, this is exactly it. And I don't care about what happens to the red box (#2), which is just there to influence the top/right on the blue box (#3).

Comment: +1 for properly explaining a question that I thought was too hard to explain but really wanted an answer to.

Comment: `position: fixed` will ignore the `overflow:hidden` of any containing element.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A trick that works is to position box #2 with `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative`. We usually put a `position: relative` on an outer box (here box #2) when we want an inner box (here box #3) with `position: absolute` to be positioned relative to the outer box. But remember: for box #3 to be positioned relative to box #2, box #2 just need to be positioned. With this change, we get:

[image]

And here is the full code with this change:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            /* Positioning */
            #box1 { overflow: hidden }
            #box2 { position: absolute }
            #box3 { position: absolute; top: 10px }

            /* Styling */
            #box1 { background: #efe; padding: 5px; width: 125px }
            #box2 { background: #fee; padding: 2px; width: 100px; height: 100px }
            #box3 { background: #eef; padding: 2px; width: 75px; height: 150px }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div id="box1">
            <div id="box2">
                <div id="box3"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i actually used `position: static` and that worked better for me

Comment: @Jason, very interesting; so you're saying that you use `position: static` on box #2 instead of `position: absolute`.

Comment: THANKS! position: absolute worked like a charm. Jason: it didn't work with static

Comment: Setting the container (#2) to static worked for me in IE 10, FF, and Chrome.

Comment: Can you elaborate why `absolute` doesn't clip but `relative` does?

Comment: It cluttered up my markup, but only slightly, and more importantly, IT WORKED, thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, we need to put #box1 { height: 100px }, otherwise the example could be misleading.

Comment: This solution will not work unless you make everything between #1 and #3 to be absolute. Practically speaking, this is impossible.

Comment: What if you don't want box#3 to be positioned relatively to box#2? IE, I want box#3 to be positioned relatively to box#1, but I want it to be visible or not based on box#2's `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Wondering what's the purpose to explain something SO visual using colors like that...

Answer (score 7):

There's no magical solution of displaying something outside an overflow hidden container.

A similar effect can be achieved by having an absolute positioned div that matches the size of its parent by positioning it inside your current relative container (the div you don't wish to clip should be outside this div):

```
#1 .mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Take in mind that if you only have to clip content on the x axis (which appears to be your case, as you only have set the div's width), you can use `overflow-x: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a way to do this as-is.  I think you might need to remove the `overflow:hidden` from div#1 and add another div within div#1 (ie as a sibling to div#2) to hold your unspecified 'content' and add the `overflow:hidden` to that instead. I don't think that overflow can be (or should be able to be) over-ridden.

Answer (score 0):

If there is other content not being shown inside the outer-div (the green box), why not have that content wrapped inside another div, let's call it `"content"`. Have overflow hidden on this new inner-div, but keep overflow visible on the green box.

The only catch is that you will then have to mess around to make sure that the content div doesn't interfere with the positioning of the red box, but it sounds like you should be able to fix that with little headache.

```
<div id="1" background: #efe; padding: 5px; width: 125px">
    <div id="content" style="overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
    <div id="2" style="position: relative; background: #fee; padding: 2px; width: 100px; height: 100px">
        <div id="3" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; background: #eef; padding: 2px; width: 75px; height: 150px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```