# Overflow inside overflow hidden & position relative grandparent

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, position, overflow

I have this dropdown menu that gets cut off due to #parent-wrapper's overflow hidden and position relative (required due to this jQuery carousel). Is there a way to make the dropdown's overflowing part display outside #parent-wrapper while keeping #parent-wrapper's overflow hidden and position relative?

Simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gNUJV/

Full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nrQSG/

```
<div id="parent-wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
a {
  color: white;
}
#parent-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#parent {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}
.dropdown ul {
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 2000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and

```
$(".dropdown").hoverIntent({
  over: function() {
    $("ul", this).show();
  },
  out: function() {
    $("ul", this).hide();
  },
  timeout: 500
});
```

Requires: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/gNUJV/1/ i think u want to this remove overflow:hidden

Comment: Thanks, but I really need overflow hidden due to this jQuery slider thing.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem using Bootstrap tooltips and dropdowns in a scrollable div.  The tooltips work fine with the overflow but add in the position relative and it triggers the browser to clip things. Bootstrap dropdowns rely on position relative for placement so not sure of a work around.

Answer (score 2):

Add a height to the #parent-wrapper on hover and it will expand.

```
$(".dropdown").hoverIntent({
 over: function() {
   $("ul", this).show().closest('#parent-wrapper').css('height','100px');
}.......
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't think that's it. I just want the dropdown UL to display outside of `#parent` and `#parent-wrapper`.

Comment: I think, if you make the height bigger than I did in my answer - like 200px, the black box ('ul') expands beyond the blue box ('#parent').

Comment: It works, thanks a bunch man! But why would it work though? It makes no sense!

Comment: What if, like in my case, the height has to be 100px?

Comment: It makes sense: you are setting a specific height of the wrapper. But if you added enough li's to go beyond that height the overflow would still be hidden.

Comment: Okay, well, it sure is an interesting hack. It does not, however, work for the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrQSG/ - would really appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  /*change this: overflow:hidden; for: */
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I really need overflow hidden - please see the full example in the above update.

Comment: So, when hovering, you want the text to go down below the border of the black box? Or do you want the black box to encompass all the text?

Comment: I guess I want the black box to encompass all the text /  for the black box's overflow to be visible / for it to display in full, with parts of it outside its parents.

Comment: you need to set the height in the `#parent` id? If not, removed

Comment: What do you mean? `#parent` does have height.

Comment: Thanks, but `#parent` should not expand like that.

Answer (score 0):

Position: Relative is the problem child here.  If you can rework the code to use Position: Absolute I think it might work.  See the following for more details...

[CSS: How to have position:absolute div inside a position:relative div not be cropped by an overflow:hidden on a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243245/css-how-to-have-positionabsolute-div-inside-a-positionrelative-div-not-be-cro?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this without using jquery by giving the dropdown a position of fixed instead of absolute.

```
.dropdown ul {
  ...
  position: fixed;
}
```

Also if you have more than the two items in your dropdown, the dropdown menu will extend automatically.