# Bubble in the scrolled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am trying to add a  bubble that pops up on on mouse over particular text on a web page and it doest work in a scrolled div (bubble is getting cut of by the edges of the div).
here is a code (the actual example page can be found at 
http://rktek.sytes.net/index3.php    ) :

```
This JS
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".bubbleInfo").each(function () {
// options
var distance = 20;     var time = 250;      var hideDelay = 500;    var hideDelayTimer = null;
// tracker
var beingShown = false;  var shown = false;    
var trigger = $('.trigger', this);      var popup = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);
// set the mouseover and mouseout on both element
$([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {

  // stops the hide event if we move from the trigger to the popup element
  if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
  // don't trigger the animation again if we're being shown, or already visible
  if (beingShown || shown) {
    return;
  } else {
    beingShown = true;
    // reset position of popup box
    popup.css({ top: -100, left: -3,  display: 'block'  })// brings the popup back in to view
     // (we're using chaining on the popup) now animate it's opacity and position
    .animate({   top: '-=' + distance + 'px',   opacity: 1 }, time, 'swing', function() {
      // once the animation is complete, set the tracker variables
      beingShown = false;   shown = true;
    });
  }
}).mouseout(function () {
  // reset the timer if we get fired again - avoids double animations
  if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);

  // store the timer so that it can be cleared in the mouseover if required
  hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    hideDelayTimer = null;
    popup.animate({
      top: '-=' + distance + 'px',    opacity: 0  }, time, 'swing', function () {
      // once the animate is complete, set the tracker variables
      shown = false;
      // hide the popup entirely after the effect (opacity alone doesn't do the job)
      popup.css('display', 'none');
    });
  }, hideDelay); }); }); });
```

And this is a CSS styling

```
* {margin: 0;  padding: 0;} 
body {  padding: 10px; }
h1 {  margin: 14px 0;  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica;  }
p {  margin: 14px 0;  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica;  }
 .bubbleInfo { position: relative;  }

/* Bubble pop-up */
.popup {  position: absolute;   display: none;  z-index: 50;  border-collapse: collapse;  }
.popup td.corner {  height: 15px;  width: 19px;  }
.popup td#topleft { background-image: url(images/bubble-1.png); }
.popup td.top { background-image: url(images/bubble-2.png); }
.popup td#topright { background-image: url(images/bubble-3.png); }
.popup td.left { background-image: url(images/bubble-4.png); }
.popup td.right { background-image: url(images/bubble-5.png); }
.popup td#bottomleft { background-image: url(images/bubble-6.png); }
.popup td.bottom { background-image: url(images/bubble-7.png); text-align: center;}
.popup td.bottom img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.popup td#bottomright { background-image: url(images/bubble-8.png); }
.popup table.popup-contents {  font-size: 12px;  line-height: 1.2em;  background-color:#fff;  color: #666; font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;}
table.popup-contents th {  text-align: right;  text-transform: lowercase;  }
table.popup-contents td {  text-align: left;  }
#main1 {overflow-y: scroll; width: 600px; height: 400px;}
```

And this is an html

```
<p> some text before scrolled div</p> <p> some text before scrolled div</p> <p> some text before scrolled div</p>

   <div id="main1"> 
   <p> some text </p>  
    <div class="bubbleInfo">
        <div>
            <span class="trigger" > this to be bubbled </span>
        </div>
        <table id="dpop" class="popup">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td id="topleft" class="corner"></td>
                <td class="top"></td>
                <td id="topright" class="corner"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="left"></td>
                <td><table class="popup-contents">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>  <th> </th>  <td>This is a bubble </td>  </tr>
                      <tr>  <th> </th>  <td>This is a bubble </td>  </tr>
                      <tr>  <th> </th>  <td>This is a bubble </td>  </tr>
                      <tr>  <th> </th>  <td>This is a bubble </td>  </tr>                       

                </tbody></table>

                </td>
                <td class="right"></td>    
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="corner" id="bottomleft"></td>
                <td class="bottom"><img width="30" height="29" alt="popup tail" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/coda/bubble-tail2.png"/></td>
                <td id="bottomright" class="corner"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <span class='bubbleInfo'>
       <span id='download3' class="trigger"> testing with span </span>
       <table id="dpop" class="popup">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td id="topleft" class="corner"></td>
                <td class="top"></td>
                <td id="topright" class="corner"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="left"></td>
                <td><table class="popup-contents">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>  <th>File:</th>  <td>coda 1.1.zip</td>  </tr>
                      <tr>  <th>Date:</th>  <td>11/30/07</td>   </tr>
                      <tr>  <th>Size:</th>  <td>17 MB</td>  </tr>
                      <tr>  <th>Req:</th>   <td>Mac OS X 10.4+</td>  </tr>                      
                      <tr id="release-notes">  <th>Read the release notes:</th> 
                                            <td><a title="Read the release notes" href="./releasenotes.html">release notes</a></td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody></table>

                </td>
                <td class="right"></td>    
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="corner" id="bottomleft"></td>
                <td class="bottom"><img width="30" height="29" alt="popup tail" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/coda/bubble-tail2.png"/></td>
                <td id="bottomright" class="corner"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </span>
  </div>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should read something about z-index...if you modifiy your z-index value on your .popup class you could do what you want ;)

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. Tried it all (z-index and position: absolute) - still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after some changes will help to set .bubbleInfo class position to absolute:

```
.bubbleInfo {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Try it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9VMY/). You can find similar posts about this problem. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243245/css-how-to-have-positionabsolute-div-inside-a-positionrelative-div-not-be-cro) one.